# Error while scraping and populate JSON in python / Use of python debug pdb

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-play, pdb

I'm scraping the Android Play Store to populate a json file with informations about apps.

Here is my code :

```
filename = "applications.txt" #file containing apps names com.app...
file = open(filename, "r")

appArray = [line.rstrip() for line in open(filename)]

def createGPscrapjson(pkg_name):
    url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=' + pkg_name
    response = get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    result = {}
    details = bs.find_all("div",{"class":"hAyfc"})
    for item in details:
        label = item.findChild('div', {'class' : 'BgcNfc'})
        value = item.findChild('span', {'class' : 'htlgb'})
        result[label.text] = value.text
        devurl = item.findChild("a",{"class":"hrTbp"})

    category = [e.text for e in bs.find_all("span",{"class":"T32cc UAO9ie"})]
    appdescription = bs.find("div",{"class":"DWPxHb"})
    #developer_link = bs.find("div",{"class":"rAknu"}).find('a').get('href')
    developer_link = bs.find("span",{"class":"T32cc UAO9ie"}).find('a').get('href')
    rating = [e.text for e in bs.find_all("div",{"class":"BHMmbe"})]
    reviewers = [e.text for e in bs.find_all("span",{"class":"AYi5wd TBRnV"})]
    price = bs.find("span",{"class":"oocvOe"}).span.find(itemprop="price").get('content')

    def developermail():
        devinfos = result['Developer'].lower() #Need to be in lower for the regex
        devmail = re.search(r'[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}',devinfos).group(0)
        if "website" in devmail:
            return(devmail[7:])
        else:
            return(devmail)

     data = {}
     data['appdata'] = []
     data['appdata'].append({
    'rating' : rating[0] if len(rating) != 0 else "No rate",
    'reviewers' : reviewers[0] if len(reviewers) != 0 else 0,
    'app_url' : 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=' + pkg_name,
    'title': html_soup.find(class_="AHFaub").text,
     'version' : result['Current Version'],
     'pkg_name' : pkg_name,
    'developer': result['Offered By'],
    'dev_website' : "No website" if "mailto:" in devurl.get('href') else devurl.get('href'),
    'downloads' : result['Installs'],
    'category' : category[1],
     'description' : appdescription.text,
     'price' : price,
     'developer_link' :developer_link,
    'operating_system' : "Android",
    'email' : developermail(),
     'updated': result['Updated']
    })

    jsonfile_one = "scrapGPdata.json"      #Get all the appS infos in one JSON
    with open(jsonfile_one, 'a+') as outfile_one:
        json.dump(data, outfile_one)

    for i in range(0,len(appArray)):
        pdb.set_trace()
        createGPscrapjson(appArray[i])
```

When I execute my code I have this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ScrapAppPage.py", line 141,
>   in 
>       createGPscrapjson(appArray[i])   File "ScrapAppPage.py", line 49, in createGPscrapjson
>       price = bs.find("span",{"class":"oocvOe"}).span.find(itemprop="price").get('content')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'

Where is my mistake and how can I use the debug mode (pdb) to see how my json file is populated?

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'``` is pretty explicit, ```bs.find("span",{"class":"oocvOe"})``` gave you ```None```, try printing it or something before calling ```.span.<everything_else>```, and also take another look at the source code of the page you are scrapping maybe there's something you've missed.

Answer (score 2):

The AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' was due to white spaces in my 'applications.txt' because none of the package was giving 'None' except an empty line.

Once I deleted all white spaces everything was working.